# I don't know what iterable means

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do an exercise with Node.js and some modules, I'm doing a Language Guessing game following a course, and I keep getting this error.

```
TypeError: pkg is not iterable
    at file:///C:/Users/alanz/OneDrive/Escritorio/HTMLExercises/examplescursos/Language%20Guesser/index.js:3:17
[90m    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)[39m
[90m    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)[39m
[90m    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)[39m
```

And this is my code:

```
import { franc } from 'franc'
import pkg from 'langs';
const [langs] = pkg;
const input = process.argv[2];
const langCode = franc(input);
if (langCode === 'und') {
    console.log("What language is this???")
} else {
    const language = pkg.where("3", langCode);
    console.log(`I think it's ${language}`)
}
```

I'm using [franc](https://github.com/wooorm/franc) and [nodejs-language](https://github.com/adlawson/nodejs-langs) as modules. And they are already installed in my package.json
I don't know why it's not working... Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

```
const [langs] = pkg;
```

This line is trying to access element 0 of pkg using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and assign that result to `langs`. The most common thing you'd use this kind of destructuring on is an array, but it can work on anything which implements an "iterator", which is just a way to tell javascript "here's how to step through my elements".

So the error is telling you that pkg is not an array, nor is it something else that implements an iterator. I'm guessing it's an object. If langs uses a default export you probably want:

```
import langs from 'langs';
```

If it uses a named export, you probably want:

```
import { langs } from 'langs'
```